# C# - Setting foreground window and giving it focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, foreground

I'm trying to make a WPF application that stays in the background and starts working when it recognizes a keystroke.
I want it to be hidden most of the time, show up when a letter key is pressed, and disappear when the spacebar is pressed.

I'm using the following code:

```
void kbdManager_LetterPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs args)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)User.GetForegroundWindow();

    // Logic..

    this.Show();

    // These worked a few times but don't anymore..
    // User.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
    // User.SetFocus(hwnd);
    // User.SwitchToThisWindow(hwnd, true);
    // User.SetActiveWindow(hwnd);
}

void kbdManager_SpacePressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs args)
{
    IntPtr hwnd = (IntPtr)User.GetForegroundWindow();

    this.Hide();

    // It seems this.Hide changes the focus?
    User.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd);
}

 [DllImport("user32")]
 public static extern int SetForegroundWindow(HWND hwnd);

 [DllImport("user32")]
 public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();
```

In order to check if GetForegroundWindow() actually works, I used the GetWindowText() method from user32.dll, and it seems to be working fine most of the time.

My problem is the focus -
When popping my application I want it to show up (and stay visible with Topmost property set to True) and then give the focus back to the window I was typing in, but instead my application gets the focus.

To solve this problem I have tried using SetForegroundWindow(), SwitchToThisWindow(), SetFocus(), and SetActiveWindow(). None of them seem to work fine for me.. The focus occasionally goes back to the main window, but not always. I've even tried different combinations but it still doesn't work consistently.

I think it might be related to the fact i'm using a keyboard listener class I downloaded to handle the keystrokes, since the debugger always takes me there -- even when I have breakpoints in the methods shown above.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your SpacePressed event handler cannot work as intended, it sets the foreground to the window that already had the foreground.  What it is *supposed* to do is completely unguessable.  Move the *hwnd* variable out of the LetterPressed event handler to get somewhere, now you have the handle of the window that was in the foreground before you called Show().

Comment: What I was thinking was - If what I was trying to do in LetterPressed worked, then the window I typed in would be in the foreground and therefore this could work. If I move the pointer out the handlers, I'll never know what is really in the foreground. I don't know how to catch an event where the focused window has changed.